# <button formtarget="_blank"></button> not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button tag that is referring to a link given as below

```
<button onclick="window.location='example.com'" formtarget="_blank"></button>
```

but its opening in the same tab what's the problem

Comment: did you have a form around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**formtarget** only work for form,
if you want for link, You can try this

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');">BUTTON TEST</button>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pajarft/aq9mmhvm/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **either**

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com')" />
```

**or**

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com');">BUTTON TEST</button>
```